# Aggregate Table with Numbers.app

Tags: numbers

I have a table featuring some outcome (column B) versus the day it happened (column A):

[image]

and I would like to produce another table with the unique dates in the first column and the total outcome of the day in the second column, looking like this:

[image]

I want the aggregated table to update itself automatically as new data are added to the first table, and I therefore tried to do it using formulae but it evaded me.

Comment: As of Numbers 11.2, you can accomplish this using a [Pivot Table](https://support.apple.com/guide/numbers/intro-to-pivot-tables-tan7ce76e776/11.2/mac/1.0).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The formula for the right column of your aggregate table is:

```
=SUMIF(Data::A,A1,Data::B)
```

The parameters to SUMIF are:

1. The column of dates which you wish to group by.
2. The individual date you wish to output the sum of (i.e. the cell to the left).
3. The column which you are taking the sum of for the group.

Comment: But how do you get the aggregate's first column? (Sort the input table by 1st column then for each row in the 2nd table pick the min that is greater than the previous row for each cell?) That's the hard part here from my point of view. That would be great if you included it.

Comment: @cglacet - I think the problem is that Numbers doesn't support formulae that output a column of values (vs. an individual value). Otherwise, an ergonomic solution here would be to have a formula defining `Aggregate::A` as something like `DISTINCT(Data::A)`. See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/269875/12509